# Command line to copy files from remote location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a script that will copy some files from LAN computer to my pc. I don't know what would be the syntax of this command.

Could anyone help me related to this?

One thing more, that in my case both the machines are using Windows.

Answer (score 3):

```
xcopy /z \\myServer\myFolder c:\
```

> /Z           Copies networked files in restartable mode.

where \myServer\myFolder is a unc path , or if you have network drive ( for example `o:`) so use :

```
xcopy /z o: c:\
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `net.exe use` to map remote share to temporary drive letter
2. `copy` or `robocopy` or `xcopy` or whever to copy the files
3. `net.exe use` to remove used mapping and free the letter

Note that Windows (95/98/ME) and WindowsNT ( NT3 / NT$ / 2000 / XP / Vista / 7) are radically different operating systems and have different DOS commands and options, especialy regarding copying.

Comment: in copy / xcopy there nothing different IMHO ( regarding copying and not unrelated stuff  such as LFN)

Comment: @RoyiNamir  There were in DOS, so i gess there was in non-NT Windows as well. But i ain't sure.